# Why are $.appendTo() not appending my <options> tag correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have this "simple" issue bugging me. I have the following JS code building a `<select>` with options:

```
var sel = $('<select id="' + elemData.id + '" name="' + elemData.id + '" onchange="folderBrowser.selectChanged(this)"></select>');
app.selectedPaths = localStorage.selectedPaths;

if (app.selectedPaths) {
    app.selectedPaths = JSON.parse(app.selectedPaths);
    app.selectedPaths.forEach(function (arr) {
        $("<option value=" + arr.path + ">" + arr.path + "</option>").appendTo(sel);
    });

    }
return sel;
```

As you see I am trying to append `<option>` elements to a `select`. I get a `option` tag with id, but not the text! `innerHTML` is blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the content of `app.selectedPaths` and `arr.path`? Are you sure the loop which does the `append()` is actually being executed? Have you checked the console for errors? You should also remove the outdated `onchange` attribute and use an unobtrusive vent handler.

Comment: Also you say you get an `option tag with id` - where is that coming from? None of the options you've shown have an `id`

Comment: Sorry about that. I`ll getting the `value` not the `id`. The `app.selectedPaths` looks like this `app.selectedPaths.push({
      owner: app.owner,
      path: path
    });` I have debugged and not getting any errors. Also checked that the string is build correctly and it does. As soon as i `appendTo(sel)` the text is removed, only getting ` <option value=(somevalue)></option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

> ```
> $("<option value=" + arr.path + ">" + arr.path + "</option>").appendTo(sel);
> ```

To this:

> ```
> $('<option value="' + arr.path + '">' + arr.path + '</option>').appendTo(sel);
> ```

`value` is usually quoted so try using double `"` and single`'` quotes.

Comment: It certainly is, sir. Happy coding.